# Compact & Repair Access 2007 Database with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access-2007, powershell-2.0, com-object, reference-library

I'm trying to use Powershell V2.0 to programatically compact and repair MS Access 2007 (.accdb) databases. The code I've created below works as part of the final code (several backup procedures occur prior to this function running).

I'm running into trouble though as all the databases are password protected and I need to run the script without the user having to enter the passwords manually. Here's my code so far:

```
Param([string]$strDBPath,[string]$strBUPath,[string]$strPwd)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function CompactAndRepairDB {

    regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll"
    regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Acedao.dll"
    regsvr32 "C:\WINNT\assembly\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao\12.0.0.__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.dll"

    $Database = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine
    $Database.CompactRepair($strDBPath,$strBUPath,"","",";pwd=" + $strPwd)

    Remove-Item $strDBPath
    Rename-Item $strBUPath $strDBPath
}

CompactAndRepairDB
```

The code throws an error though as below:

> Cannot load COM type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine.
>   At U:\Scripts\CompactRepairDatabase.ps1:11 char:27
>   +     $Database = New-Object <<<<  -ComObject Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotLoadComObjectType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

How do I load the correct library / COM object to complete the operation or is there an alternative method to achieve the `.CompactRepair` method using the password? Thanks

Comment: Is there much point in a password if you are going to include it in script?

Comment: @Fionnuala The script is held in a secure location which can only be accessed by one user account so I'm not concerned about access to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-ComObject` from the line:

```
$Database = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine
```

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine` will be a managed interop wrapper around `DAO.DBEngine` so you don't need the `-ComObject` switch.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm still receiving an error `Cannot find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.` Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Kev; your display name is causing some issues... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269262/username-obfuscates-content; I'm going to change the name to Kev for now - can you consider a less disruptive visual? For reference - the old value: K̨̩̭͚̘̗̻̞͈͖̙͙e̗̦̼̳̣̦͜͡v̢̝̟̗̱̯͉

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access
$File =  "Your.accdb"
$DbEng = new-object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngineClass # no square bracket []
$Db = $DbEng.OpenDatabase($File)
$Db
```